Since Fedora 41, how do you list packages installed explicitly by the user
Since Fedora 41, the following command does not work anymore:
$ sudo dnf history userinstalled
Unknown argument "userinstalled" for command "history".

The list of Changes between DNF and DNF5 does not mention this change.
Using dnf, how do you list the packages that have been explicitly installed by the user?

There's a --userinstalled option for dnf repoquery. That help any?

Not a Fedora user, but have you checked the documentation, man dnf?

@ChrisDavies : did you know 99% of questions on all stackexchange.com sites have their answer directly or indirectly coming from the manuals or reference books? The purpose of such sites is to not have to reread thousand of manual pages just to imagine where on earth dnf developers have the great idea to change options from one dnf command to another each time they release a new version of dnf.

@JérômeRadix I'm with you on the frustration of having "standard" options changed. (I still disagree with the way that the ls behviour was changed.) However, if you find unexpected behaviour it's always worth reading the documentation
